# Expected Value of $X^r$

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $f(x)$ be the probability density of a continous random variable $X$ defines as: \begin{equation} f(x) = \begin{cases} 2(1-x) & 0 < x < 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \end{equation} Prove that: $$E[X^r] = \frac{2}{(r+1)(r+2)}$$

My partial answer:

$$E[X^r] = 2\int\limits_0^1 x^r(1-x)dx = 2\int\limits_0^1 x^r-x^{r+1}dx=2\bigg[\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1} - \frac{x^{r+2}}{r+2}\bigg]^1_0$$

This is where I am stuck. If I plug in 1, I get 0. If I plug in 0, I get 0. I do not know how the answer is gotten from this point. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you plug in $1$ you *don't* get 0, you get $$\displaystyle\frac{1}{r+1}-\frac{1}{r+2}=\frac{1}{(r+1)(r+2)}$$ for the square bracket.

Comment: There is no error. You are not stuck. You have won.

Comment: If I plug $x=1$ I get $\large{\frac{1^{r+1}}{r+1} - \frac{1^{r+2}}{r+2}}$ $=\frac{1}{r+1} - \frac{1}{r+2}$

Comment: Thanks everybody. I feel dumb. It was such an obvious mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plug in $x = 1$ you get:

$$2\left[\frac{1}{r+1}-\frac{1}{r+2}\right]= 2\left[\frac{(r+2) - (r+1)}{(r+1)(r+2)}\right] = \frac{2}{(r+1)(r+2)}.$$

As required. Your answer is complete and correct!